# A views page as “Output this field as a link” in a block (Drupal)

Tags: views, blocks, navigation

Hello I´m trying to get a link from my thumbnails gallery http://www.nellens.com/home/photos to the full size gallery http://www.nellens.com/home/photos-full for each "Photo" content type that I have, but when I put the node (I tried with 2 methods, first creating a text field where I put the URL and another following this tutorial drupal.org/node/1215544, so I put in this case [counter]), but nothing overwrites my output link, it always lands to /content, showing all the fields of my content type, and I just want to show my full size pics fields only, not all the fields. My content type is made by a thumbnail image, the full size images that have relation between them and a tag field. So I did create all as in the FAQ tutorial but when I try to overwrite the thumbnail in the block to show the relative images and to land to the page /photos-full, it just does not work, it always lands me to /content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images can automatically be made to link to either their node or directly to the image itself using the 'manage display' tab on the content type: `admin/structure/types/manage/content_type/display`
[image: selecting image link destination in field display]

I would simply make your view an unordered list of teasers and link each image to the file itself if you only want to display the image, or if you would like to have other fields such as a description you could select content and link it out to the node. I am not sure how you have your content type setup but best practice would be to have the fields setup similar to the screenshot below. You would have one image field per photograph and simply use the teaser display mode and image styles to display thumbnails in a listing.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did help me a lot! Now it´s working, thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did help me a lot! Now it´s working, thanks again.
http://nellens.com/home/photos

Now I am having problems with the captions I think the module Image Field Caption is a little bit abandoned, would you recommend me another that would be easy to manipulate? I would like to inject the css into the views (as I am doing it now with Code per Views Page Display) but this Image Field Caption module seems to be too static. Thanks again and again.